# can't add back html element after using detach

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add the element back after I remove the html using the `remove()` function. For some reason when I call the `add()` function, the **remove** variable loses the html DOM. If I put the `remove.insertAfter('#element');` outside of the ajaxSuccess(), it works. I'm using ajaxSuccess() because I want the ajax to finish first before I could show the user the element again.

```
    var remove;
    function remove() {

//there is a ajax call here

       $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
          remove = $('#myDiv').detach(); //or should I use remove()?
       });
    }

    function add() {

//there is an ajax call here

       $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
          remove.insertAfter('#main');
       });
    }

    <div id="main">
       <div id="myDiv">

       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: And why is everything wrapped in the `ajaxSuccess` handler, that's not the way to go here! Post the ajax code as well!

Answer (score 0):

as per api documentation from

[detach()](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)

It states to use the detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements 
In your case, it may be the DOM is not ready after the ajax call, try to delay the action by few seconds when you add the element back and see if it works. I mean to deffer the action of adding the element back into the DOM. Just a suggestion